# JSPG0301E: Invalid attribute, valueChangeListener, for deferred method returning void

Tags: java, jsf, websphere-8, valuechangelistener

While migrating JSF application from WebSphere 6.1 to WebSphere 8.5.5 we faced following exception.

> 0000009b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/content/provinceStatHolidayContent.jsp]: com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating xxx.jsp:
>       JSPG0301E: Invalid attribute, valueChangeListener, for deferred method returning void.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far to solve the problem? Can you provide any code? The error message is quite clear, you have an invalid attribute vor one of your methods. We need more input to help.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bug tracker. Do you have a question?

Comment: I Answer my own question to share solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet into concern jsp page resolve the problem.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral="false"%>
```